# Normalizing a Categorical Ordinal Variable

Tags: categorical-data, normalization, ordinal-data

I am trying to normalize my data in which I collected number of time people pick their hair and their stress level which ranges from 1 (no stress) to 5 (high stress) and try to create a graph in order to see if stress level has an effect on the number of times people pick their hair. Should I normalize my data to stress level 1 which can be considered as a possible negative control? If I do the percentages are mostly over 100% since higher stress seems to have higher number of hair picks. What should I do to normalize my data?

Comment: Can you just plot a bar chart with number of hair picks in each of the five bars? It isn't clear to me why any kind of normalization would be warranted.

Comment: Hi! since it was a survey the groups of stress levels have different sample sizes so I was thinking that I should normalize my data.

Comment: Try dividing each count by the total count.